# How do I find out which control has focus in .NET Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls, focus

How do I find out which control has focus in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`Form.ActiveControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) may be what you want.

Comment: Just want to point out that if you have changed something (set a .Text property for example) it will return the control that you last used. including setting things like the .Text not always the control that has focus

Answer (score 15):

Note that a single call to ActiveControl is not enough when hierarchies are used. Imagine:

```
Form
    TableLayoutPanel
        FlowLayoutPanel
            TextBox (focused)
```

`(formInstance).ActiveControl` will return reference to `TableLayoutPanel`, not the `TextBox`

So use this (full disclosure: adapted from [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439606/15639))

```
  Function FindFocussedControl(ByVal ctr As Control) As Control
    Dim container As ContainerControl = TryCast(ctr, ContainerControl)
    Do While (container IsNot Nothing)
      ctr = container.ActiveControl
      container = TryCast(ctr, ContainerControl)
    Loop
    Return ctr
  End Function
```

Comment: Sample use:
  Private Sub frmPartes_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles 
Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            Dim Ct As Windows.Forms.Control

            Ct = FindFocussedControl(Me.ActiveControl)

            If TypeOf (Ct) Is TextBox Or TypeOf (Ct) Is System.Windows.Forms.UserControl Then

                Filtrar()

                e.Handled = True

                e.SuppressKeyPress = True

            End If

        End If

    End Sub



maybe are necesisary use this: Windows.Forms.Control  instead only control

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  ActiveControl alone doesn't do what you need every time (which is what sent me looking here!).

Answer (score 3):

In C# I do this:

```
        if (txtModelPN != this.ActiveControl)
            txtModelPN.BackColor = Color.White;
```

txtModelPN is a textbox that I am highlighting on enter and mouseEnter and de-highlighting on Leave,MouseLeave. Except if it is the current control I don't set the background back to white.

The VB equivalent would be like this

```
IF txtModelPN <> Me.ActiveControl Then
   txtModelPN.BackColor = Color.White
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ActiveControl propert of the form and can use that control.

```
me.ActiveControl
```

Or

```
Form.ActiveControl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find by Control Name .

```
    If DataGridView1.Name = Me.ActiveControl.Name Then
        TextBox1.Visible = True
    Else
        TextBox1.Visible = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following:

```
Private bFocus = False
Private Sub txtUrl_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUrl.MouseEnter
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name <> txtUrl.Name Then
        bFocus = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtUrl_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles txtUrl.MouseUp
    If bFocus Then
        bFocus = False
        txtUrl.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```

I set the Variable only on MouseEnter to improve the magic

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines:

```
Protected Function GetFocusControl() As Control
    Dim focusControl As Control = Nothing

    ' Use this to get the Focused Control: 
    Dim focusHandle As IntPtr = GetFocus()
    If IntPtr.Zero.Equals(focusHandle) Then          
      focusControl = Control.FromHandle(focusHandle)
    End If

    ' Note that it returns NOTHING if there is not a .NET control with focus 
    Return focusControl
End Function
```

I think this code came from windowsclient.net, but it's been a while so...

Comment: Please let me downvote the answer until you complete it. The call of `GetFocus()` hangs in nowhere and the answer in this form simply won't work.

Comment: Upvote - while this does require P/Invoke and the answer doesn't fully explain how to call the function, a bit more searching for ".NET GetFocus" can solve that. While this may not be the author's intent, the question is not limited to the current application and this is the only answer that even attempts to find the actual active control regardless of where/what it is.