# how to find out which textbox is currenlty selected

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 text-boxes, how do I find out which text-box is currently selected (has focus). I am unable to come up with anything.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public activeTextBox As TextBox = CType(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        activeTextBox.Text = activeTextBox.Text & "This is text 1"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        activeTextBox.Text = activeTextBox.Text & "This is the text 2"
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that this is a Windows Forms application.

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660173/how-do-i-find-out-which-control-has-focus-in-net-winforms) offers two possible suggestions:

```
Me.ActiveControl
```

Or, you can write a method using the Windows API to get the handle of the control that currently has the focus. This [article](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/26/how-do-i-find-out-which-control-has-focus.aspx) on WindowsClient.Net has an example.

However, each of these options will only work if the TextBox still has the focus at the time the method is called.

Within your button event handler, you are trying to find out which was the last active TextBox in order to do something with it. In this situation, `Me.ActiveControl` will not be much use because the TextBox control will lose focus as soon as you click on the button. The sample code below shows how you might use the Enter and Leave events of the TextBox to keep track of which TextBox was the most recently active. I have assumed the TextBox is called TextBox1.

```
        Public Class Form1
            Public activeTextBox As TextBox 

Private Sub TextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter, TextBox3.Enter
   activeTextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
End Sub    

            Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
              If (activeTextBox IsNot Nothing) Then
              activeTextBox.Text = activeTextBox.Text & "This is text 1"
End If
          End Sub

          Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

              If (activeTextBox IsNot Nothing) Then
              activeTextBox.Text = activeTextBox.Text & "This is the text 2"
End If
          End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: What's the error? You need to put the code inside a method or event handler.

Comment: I have put the screen-shot above .

Comment: The problem you have is that you have put the type conversion for activeTextBox at form level outside a method or event handler. There will be no "ActiveControl" when the form is instantiated, therefore the cast will not work. I have edited the sample code to try to explain it better.

Comment: `activeTextBox.Text = CType(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox)`
Error: 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: What does this  mean `activeTextBox.Text & "This is text 1`

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

Comment: The problem you have is that as soon as the button is clicked, the textbox loses focus and the button gains focus instead. Therefore, you can't use Me.ActiveControl in the button event handler, as this will contain a reference to the button, not the textbox. You need to find a way of keeping track of the last textbox that got the focus. Search Google for TextBox.Enter and TextBox.Leave events.

Comment: @Jazza +1 for helping so extensively. i'll delete my answer since Jazza's answer covers the same ground so much more thoroughly

Comment: I've updated the example to show how Enter and Leave events may be used to track which was the last active textbox.

Comment: Error:'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

Comment: Try `IsNot Nothing` instead, with no space

Comment: Well No Error now but the textbox shows nothing and besides do I have to write Text Enter and text leave methods for all the textboxes ?

Comment: Yes, either each TextBox will need Enter events or you can have 1 event handler for all 3.

Comment: That's a good idea :) Why is that the text not showing up in the textbox ?

Comment: @Jazza Is jazza your real name ? (just curious to know)

Comment: No - just a nickname I've had since I was a child