# How to get Active TextBox Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 textboxes in the form textbox1 and textbox2 (Yeah was pretty lazy)
and the task of creating a copy and paste like function for the application
(for practice reasons)

but I have no idea how the program will determine which textbox is currently the active one

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) //Copy
        {

        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) //Paste
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the sender to a `TextBox` and get its name or whatever identifies your textboxes.
Do it responsibly, use `as` : `var textBox = sender as TextBox` and then check it for null

EDIT: the event handler must be assigned to both `TextBox`elements not to the form

Comment: do I have to do it for each of my textboxes?...

Comment: This will only work if that `KeyDown` handler is assigned to the `TextBox`es' `KeyDown` events. From it's name I thought it's assigned to the `Form`'s event, so `sender` is always the `Form`, not the `TextBox`.

Comment: @kennedydelrosario yeah, you have to asign this event to each `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have a question already got an answer.

[Form.ActiveControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660173/how-do-i-find-out-which-control-has-focus-in-net-windows-forms) may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which `TextBox` is activated by using the [`ContainsFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox activeTextBox = textBox1.ContainsFocus 
                    ? textBox1
                    : (textBox2.ContainsFocus ? textBox2 : null);     

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) //Copy
    {

    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) //Paste
    {

    }
}
```

Or alternatively the [`Form.ActiveControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845144.aspx) property:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox activeTextBox = ActiveControl as TextBox;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) //Copy
    {

    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) //Paste
    {

    }
}
```