# Fastest way to get focused control in WinForms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using ProcessCmdKey in my main form window for the application to test for certain keys and give Space, Right, Left, and a few others special processing. ProcessCmdKey in the main form is called even if the user is typing in a TextBox inside a nested set of user controls. I don't want to process the Space key when they are focused on a TextBox control, since they'd never be able to type a space. How can I test for the type of the currently focused window on an application wide basis?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the window handle with this:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

Then you can get the .NET control associated with that handle (if there is one) with [Control.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Found something that appears to work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    IntPtr wndHandle = GetFocus();
    Control focusedControl = FromChildHandle(wndHandle);
    if(focusedControl is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextBoxMaskBox)
    {
       return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    ...
}
```