# KeyDown does not trigger after switching tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I am using Winforms dialog with multiple tabs (`tab1` and `tab2`). Both of the tabs have `KeyPreview = true`.

On `tab1` when I hit `W` on my keyboard, the `KeyDown` (for `tab1`) event triggers successfully. However upon switching to `tab2` and then back to `tab1`, the same key does not trigger anymore.

Any idea on what is causing the problem?

Comment: Could be that the tab header has input focus?

Comment: @Micky How do I check for input focus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814209/fastest-way-to-get-focused-control-in-winforms-c

Comment: KeyPreview is a property of the Form class.  Which has absolutely nothing to do with tabs so the question makes little sense.  KeyPreview is a hokey VB6 compatibility property, override ProcessCmdKey() to do it the .NET way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method around this:

Basically in the `OnClick` method in `tab1`, I simply call `this.Focus()`.

So the user has to click back onto the tab page, and he will be able to press a keyboard command after this.