# how can understand which control has been focused?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, panel

I have many controls that i make in run time and i locate them in my panel on the form,now i want to delete each control that the user selected ,how can i understand that which control has been focused ??
thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you need [FocusManager.GetFocusedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.getfocusedelement.aspx) if you are using WPF
or [Form.ActiveControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) for WinForms.

For panel it will be:

```
if (panel.ContainsFocus)
{
    Control currentlyFocused =
        panel.Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(control => control.Focused);
}
```

Comment: i want to find on my panel,not on my form.

Comment: @na.farzane, are you using WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ActiveControl`. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app)