# how add a string to focused texbox in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a char to focused texbox in `winform c#`. how can i do that ? actually i want control `e.KeyChar` in `myform_KeyPress` event.

```
private void add_user_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r' && hidden_scan_textbox.Text != "")
        {
            shomare_shenasai_view.Text = hidden_scan_textbox.Text;
            hidden_scan_textbox.Text = "";
        }
        if (e.KeyChar != '\r')
        {
            hidden_scan_textbox.Text += e.KeyChar;
       //here i want to add e.KeyChar to focused texbox
            e.KeyChar = '\0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: just added the char required why do you need it to be `e.KeyChar`

Comment: why not leave how is - char will be entered to focused textbox automatically by default :)

Comment: i work with a `barcode scanner` so i need to handle it by myself

Comment: ok so whats the problem? you want to find which textbox is focused?

Comment: exactly, i just want to know where is the focus in my form? then i know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFormInstance.ActiveControl` returns the current focused control in the form.
Be careful because it could (depending on how your form is built) also be another control and not a textbox.

Have also a look at here:
[What is the preferred way to find focused control in WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app)

Comment: +1.. ahh ActiveControl! just couldn't remember that property, looked for FocusedControl or something :)

Comment: link was so helpful problem solved ;) but with every key pressed windows play a sound. why is that ? i don't know why windows do that !

Comment: @hamze: Sorry, no idea. We need more code to try to understand the problem, you could possibly post a new question...