# How do you determine if an item is selected?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to determine if an item, in my case the webbrowser, is selected?

example: `control.select() = true;`

note: I know that the example is not correct, but it is only to show an example of what I want.

When I do a button that executes: `webBrowser1.Select();`

It selects correctly but if its executed twice. It becomes unselected.

I understand why it happens, but is there way to make it selected that doesn't get unselected if executed twice.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context of your question? It almost sounds like you're asking in the context of Winforms but I can't be sure. Can you verify? Do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ContainsFocus` or `Focused` property to determine if control has focus.