# Determine if button/window is active winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to automate Installation Wizard and I won't to know if child button in window is active. This need to make some kind a log file while test is performing. Any help will do)

Comment: Check what is the `ActiveControl`

Comment: As I understand you need to determine a focused control. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app

Comment: I find the solution using IsWindowEnabled(IntPtr hWnd), see this http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.iswindowenabled

Answer (score 0):

Controls expose both an [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) and a [Focused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused.aspx)property. What you're challenge exactly? Figuring out the button is active? Or actually locating the button in order do test it?