# How to: Refresh PropertyGrid when user is not editing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please bear with me if I made any mistakes.

**Background:**
I have a Winform PropertyGrid that displays status such as gain and exposure from a Camera object. User can control/edit camera properties easily through PropertyGrid. Meanwhile, camera object periodically queries latest status from a physical camera and cause a refresh in PropertyGrid through INotifyProperfyChanged.

**Problem:**
If a refresh took place while user was entering/editing data on propertygrid (such as entering a new shutter time value), focus was suddenly lost and entered value would be replaced by new value from camera. This resulted in a unfriendly UI experience.

**Question:**
How to prevent PropertyGrid from performing refresh when user was doing editing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited my answer with the code itself at the top, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit (1:54 PM CST)**: The code you want is this, as you would wrap your update code / method call to do the update within it:

```
if(FindFocusedControl(this).GetType().ToString() != "GridViewEdit")
{

}
```

This will check if the active control,in this case a cell within the propertygrid, is active and skip over the nested code if true.

---

Utilizing the following method from [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439606/771928) you should be able to wrap whatever code does the updating in an If conditional to check to see what control is being focused/used. If the control in use is the propertygrid, don't do anything.

```
    public static Control FindFocusedControl(Control control)
    {
        var container = control as ContainerControl;
        while (container != null)
        {
            control = container.ActiveControl;
            container = control as ContainerControl;
        }
        return control;

    }
```

If you wish to try it, pass it your form and check out the results:

```
var a = FindFocusedControl(this);
```

As you are a new user, if this works out for you, you may accept an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of a provided answer. This lets other users know what worked for you when they come upon your question later.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. PropertyGrid is now only refreshed when not focused. Although this could delay live data update when a user always focused on PropertyGrid, such behaviour is way better than before.

Comment: That could easily be resolved via some sort of inactivity timer in which the focus is set to another control, perhaps a label or the form itself, after a set amount of time. Glad to have helped, and welcome to SO!

Comment: Timer is a great idea! Thanks again!