# Detecting which type of control is active

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

for detect that which controls is activated in windows form

```
this.ActiveControl = NameOfControl;
```

how about detect type of control , for example active control is button or textbox ?

New Edit:

i want to do something on keypress if active control is type of textBox else do nothing

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (this.ActiveControl == xxxx)
            {
                //do SomeThing
            }
              return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

in xxx i should type of name of control , but how can i do for all control that is type of text box?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app

Comment: Ah I see. I think the `is` operator is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether an active control is a Button or TextBox you could use the `is` operator. The is operator checks if an object is compatible with a given type. If the `Control` is compatible with a `Button` and the expression yields true, then the Control *is* a Button.

```
if (ActiveControl is Button)
{

}
else if (ActiveControl is TextBox)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.GetType()`, for example  `this.ActiveControl.GetType() == typeof(Button)`

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all controls on your Form and set an event handler for the GotFocus  Event. In this Event handler you would set the variable:

```
    Control ActiveControl = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
           if(c is TextBox)
           {
            c.GotFocus += (s, o) =>
                {
                    this.ActiveControl = s as Control;
                };
           }
        }
    }
```

When you use your ActiveControl objekt test for the type with the "is" operator.