# C# PropertyGrid Property MouseClick Event

Tags: c#, listview, event-handling, mouseevent, propertygrid

I have two **tabPages** with the **ListView** and **PropertyGrid** on each. Every object from the **MyListView** on the **tabPage1** has the field with the name of an object from the **MyListView2**. When I *MouseClick* at this field I would like to *select* **tabPage2**, then find and *select* the required object.

I was glad to get the further code work properly in the *debug mode*. Though when I tried to launch the executable file in the debug folder, I've got ***"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception*** after the *MouseClick* at the required field.
I guess, this is the aftermath of using **ActiveControl** inside the **PrintPropertyGrid()** method, though I have had no idea yet how to realize it the other way.

How to get rid of that exception?

```
private void MyListView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyListView.IsHandleCreated)
        if (MyListView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            PrintPropertyGrid(MyListView.SelectedIndices[0]);
}

private void PrintPropertyGrid(int index)
{
    MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = MyList[index];
    foreach (Control c in MyPropertyGrid.ActiveControl.Controls)
        c.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(propertyGrid_MouseClick);
}

private void propertyGrid_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyPropertyGrid.SelectedGridItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name.Equals("Conversion"))
    {
        string name;
        name = MyPropertyGrid.SelectedGridItem.Value.ToString();
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            ListViewItem foundItem = MyListView2.FindItemWithText(name, false, 0, true);
            if (foundItem != null)
                foundItem.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at myProject.FormMain.PrintPropertyGrid(Int32 selector, PropertyGrid propertyGrid, Int32 index) in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio2012\Projects\myProject\myProject\FormMain.cs:line 96
   at myProject.FormMain.MyListView2_ItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio2012\Projects\myProject\myProject\FormMain.cs:line 286
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.OnItemSelectionChanged(ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs     e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmReflectNotify(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: What's the exception full stack frame?

Comment: Don't know whether I had got your comment, anyway, I added the exception text.

Comment: So, with the source code line you can know what's null. I suppose it's SelectedGridItem or SelectedGridItem.Value

Comment: The first line points at the 'foreach (Control c in MyPropertyGrid.ActiveControl.Controls)', that's why I suspect ActiveControl.

Comment: Ah ok yes probably. You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app