# Preventing a TextBox leave event when loosing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

> **How to stop textbox leave event on clicking on linklable/button while Textbox was in focus?**

I have a textbox `TextBox1`. On leave event of it, I have to validate it's text. And as per text of it, I have to populate suggestion of next textbox `TextBox2`.

so in this process, when I'm clicking on a link-label [which is there for different reason] while `TextBox1` is in focus, It is firing Leave event [which is obvious] and calling validating functionality [which is not supposed to be called - because user have not left textbox after completing input- It was triggered by linkable click].

I have tried to unsubscribe Leave event on link-label's click event but that doesn't help as leave event is being fired in first place.

what should be done in this case ?

EDIT :
posting related code,

I'm Having same Event Handler for both textbox

```
    private void txtBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.Visible = false;

            #region TextBox 1
            if (textBox.Equals(txtBox1))
            {
                //Text Box 1 validation
                //Populating Suggestions for TextBox2
                //Passing focus on Textbox 2
            }
            #endregion
            #region TextBox 2
            else if (textBox.Equals(txtBox2))
            {
                //Text Box 2 validation
            } 
            #endregion
     }
```

As I've mentioned earlier, Link label is there for different and I cannot disable or hide it during operation on Text box.

One observation is,
When I click on Link label, **Leave event of text box raise first and after that Click Event of Link Label**, so we cannot perform any logic (like unsubscribing leave event of Textbox or something else) on Link-Label's click event - as by the time validation process would be done which we don't want.

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, ...? (You should add this to tag list).

Comment: @SamusArin I'm using winForms.

Comment: Can you please post related code, specifically the TextBox leave event handler and validation routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `link label`, it becomes focused control. What you can do is - find the focused control of the form in `textbox1_leave` event handler. If it is **not** that `link label` then only the functionality for populating suggestions of `textbox2` should be done.

This link should be helpful for you to find out focused control of the form - [What is the preferred way to find focused control in WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app)

Comment: Yeah I was figuring something along these lines as well, it sounds as if validation is being fired unconditionally from the leave event, but still want to see the code to be sure there is nothing else going on.

Comment: @SamusArin , yes. Validation is being fired unconditionally. And whatever Arpit has suggested, It is helping me out in this situation.