# Implement form level shortcuts without intercept child control's input

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making form level shortcuts with form application.

First, it works with strip menus, however their shortcuts must be combination of any modifier and a word or decimal key. I need only a word or decimal key shortcut. Therefore it does not fit my needs.

And I tried a method that `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events with form's `KeyPreview` set to `true`. If I handled the word or decimal keys with `Handled` and `SuppressKeyPress` set to `true` in those events, the child control cannot receive the input even though the control is `TextBox` or `NumericUpDown` that is a control that allows text input. Overriding `ProcessCmdKey` has the same issue.

And then, I tried to check the focusing control actually needs the input by calling focusing control's `IsInputKey` and `IsInputChar`. Yes, you cannot call them normally because these methods are `protected`. I used reflection. But I had no luck. These were not working as I expected.

Finally, I applied a branch that checks the focusing control is `TextBox` or something allowing input. I had no luck with this either. Because the `NumericUpDown`'s real focus control is a private class called `UpDownBase.UpDownEdit`. It means that some other controls can have similar mechanism that cannot expect in build time. In short, it can cause bugs.

I think, I could solve this issue if there was a way to catch unhandled input in last key handling phase such like bubbling. But I couldn't find information about it for form applications.

Do I have to override **ALL** of child controls' `ProcessCmdKey`s?

Really isn't there a fancy way to solve this problem?

Comment: WinForms is designed in a way that it is easy to do usual things... So if something is hard to do, it is suspicious as your UI would not works the way most user expect it to work.

Comment: Are you talking about system-wide key inputs? It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is my quick solution. I have changed searching focused control method. In previous, it searched to the depest control. The source was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439606/1655141). Currently, searching a type is exists in control tree to solve `NumericUpDown` case. It works fine but I don't think it's fast.

Comment: @bic As I wrote, form level. In other words, handle shorcut's routine when my form is foreground form and the currently focused control does not allow text input such as `Button`, `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` etc.

Comment: @donggas90: "I'm making form or global level shorcuts with form application." sorry, this is where my confusion came from.

Comment: @bic My apologies. That sentence can cause confusion that you've done.

Comment: @donggas90: No problem, this seems to be what you're looking for. The key term is application-level keyboard hooks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384189/99804

Comment: @bic Thanks for link. I didn't test about it but it seems not filtering the situation that focusing control allow text input. In this case, the shortcut must not be fired.

Comment: @donggas90: Well you can add filtering to the event handler as you need. Thats all I've got at the moment.

Comment: @bic Form application already can receive all of inputs in form level. Therefore need not hook. Filtering the case is real problem. I mentioned about `NumericUpDown` case in original question. In the end, I applied a temporary solution that worte it in above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161487/discussion-between-bic-and-donggas90).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my quick solution. I have changed searching focused control method.

In previous, it searching to the deepest active control. The source was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439606/1655141). This way caused skipping `NumericUpDown` case because it is also a container, and returned its private control.

Therefore, I have changed it to searching a control **type** instead taking the deepest one in active control chain.

```
static bool IsFocusedControlType<T>(Control control, out T focused)
    where T : Control
{
    if (control is T t)
    {
        focused = t;
        return true;
    }
    var container = control as IContainerControl;
    while (container != null)
    {
        control = container.ActiveControl;
        if (control is T tt)
        {
            focused = tt;
            return true;
        }
        container = control as IContainerControl;
    }
    focused = null;
    return false;
}

static bool CanConsumeKey(Form sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsFocusedControlType(sender, out NumericUpDown ud))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (IsFocusedControlType(sender, out TextBox tb) && !tb.ReadOnly)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (IsFocusedControlType(sender, out ListView lv) && lv.LabelEdit)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (IsFocusedControlType(sender, out TreeView tv) && tv.LabelEdit)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (IsFocusedControlType(sender, out ComboBox cb) && 
        cb.DropDownStyle != ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It works fine but I don't think it's fast.